In the context of arguments, what is the meaning of "This is Japan!" (ここは日本だよ)?
It seems that this is a phrase that Japanese people will say to foreigners in an argument.
Some examples of the usage of this phrase are as follows.
First example
A foreign woman works in an environment in Japan where she has to speak English. This is fine, because English is her native language. She has taken classes in the Japanese language, but she doesn't feel fluent or comfortable with her Japanese. One day, she got into an argument with a Japanese person who wasn't a coworker. The Japanese person was convinced that she did something when she didn't. She tried to be the bigger person and apologize in English for the thing that she didn't do. The Japanese person said, "This is Japan! You need to speak Japanese!"
Second example
It is a fact of life that married couples will get into disagreements or arguments over things. There are cases where a foreigner will argue with their Japanese spouse over something, and the Japanese spouse will consistently say, "This is Japan!" The Japanese spouse might even make a comment about クソ外人 (Romanized spelling: "kuso gaijin", English translations: "s___ty foreigner," "f___ing foreigner," "damn foreigner"). I wonder if this is a sign of a deteriorating marriage.
I don't know if there are cases where a Japanese person will say, "This is Japan!" to another Japanese person, but if there are, I haven't heard of them.
What does a Japanese person mean when they say "This is Japan!" in an argument?
P.S. Someone wants to know how I believe the expression does not mean what it literally means.
Well, please allow me to show you this Reddit post.
One comment towards that post is as follows.

Just keep in mind that statements like this are shorthand for "You're doing something I don't personally like, so if I make the claim that my personal opinions are a matter of national importance, that will somehow assert dominance over you and force you to make changes to make me personally more comfortable."
In other words, ignore. Or break wind loudly while making deadpan eye contact.

Another comment essentially says that some racists will resort to saying "This is Japan!" just to dominate and bully random foreigners.
I hope that helps.

Obviousness is obvious.  ‍♂️  Am I missing something?

How is this different from any other country or place in the world?  Americans say, "This is America"; Europeans say "This is the EU"; the French will say, "This is France".  It's not limited to countries but also cities and regions:  "This is SF" or "This is New York", "This is the South" or "This is the Midwest".  There is a proverb, "When in Rome, do as the Romans do."  Saying "This is Japan" would seem to echo these very same sentiment.

I find this question very odd. Could you add how you believe the expression to not mean what it literally means? Also, your second scenario makes up a situation which I find quite unusual to begin with, then passes imaginary judgement on it: "I wonder if this is a sign of a deteriorating marriage."

Do you really know multiple couples where the Japanese spouse is calling the other spouse クソ外人?

Off track but actually there are a lot of situations where a Japanese person says "This is Japan!" to another Japanese person.

@Leebo: Personally? No. I only came across a Reddit post where an American woman talks about how her marriage to a Japanese man is breaking down, because he throws things, yells at her that "This is Japan!" and says "kuso gaijin" either to her or about foreigners in general.

@Leebo: In addition, one person who commented on that Reddit post is a man who married a Japanese woman a long time ago. He says that arguments with her went normally at first, but ten years into the marriage, she took to retorting "This is Japan!" and saying "kuso gaijin" either to him or in general. He says that she is being nationalist/racist. For all I know, both of them are not even trying to understand each other's perspective.

@Leebo: To sum up, I only know of two people from Reddit who are married to Japanese people who apparently say "kuso gaijin" in their presence, which is not the same as knowing them personally, wouldn't you agree? I don't know if this sort of thing is common, but I certainly hope not!

This seems just very human.
If you're living some place where you're most likely not going to be considered a native, then folks will remark upon that.  Particularly, in conflicts that may arise from cultural differences.
This can happen between nations.  This can happen between regions within a nation.  Even different cities may have different cultures.  Businesses may have differences that may be emphasized by saying, "This is ABC Corp" or something like that--because different businesses have a different ethos.
On one level, regional pride might prompt someone to make such comments.  In Fukuoka, folks believe theirs is the best ramen you can find in Japan.  In the States, large regions have pride in what makes them stand out such as pride in the regional hospitality of the South.
If you're getting into an argument with someone, fluency can become a hindrance to clear communication.  If a foreigner is consistently being misunderstood, then the attitude may be, "you need to improve your language skills in Japanese because you're not communicating clearly."  Certainly the onus is not on the Japanese to improve their English to communicate with their employee who is working for them in Japan.
"This is Japan" can be a reminder for someone to reflect on their cultural presuppositions.  It can be an admonishment to recall that local customs, expectations, notions of polite, expedient, or proper may and do differ and need to be kept in mind.
